# Jupyter Kernel Dead upon training LightFM Model `fit_partial`

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openmp, lightfm

When initially importing `from lightfm.datasets import fetch_movielens`, I get the following output:

UserWarning: LightFM was compiled without OpenMP support. Only a single thread will be used.

Then, I create the model:
`model = LightFM(learning_rate=0.05, loss='warp', no_components=64, item_alpha=0.001)`

However, upon running `model.fit_partial(train, item_features=movielens['item_features'], epochs=20 )`, my kernel always dies.

I have tried this with both Python 3.8.0 and Python 3.11.2

I tried searching for an OpenMP package or packages that give OpenMP support, but the same error persists. Also, I heavily reduced the size of training data, which still had no effect.

Comment: Do you know if it's running out of memory, and dying for that reason?

Comment: I don't think it's running out of memory. Even after reducing training Data size, the same thing happens.